# How can I customize references with natbib package?

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, natbib, custom-bib

I am done with my paper and I am trying to get the references by:

(1) Order by the appearance

(2) This format:[Number] Surname, name-initial (Year).

I am using the natbib package, I think I gotta make a bst file to get this result, but I have never done it before.

So basically my code is:

```
% in the preamble.
\usepackage{natbib}

% In text
Cleansing effect literature traces back to Joseph Schumpeter (1939 --1942). \citep{Caballero_Hammour_1991}.

% At the end
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliog.bib}
```

I know I have to change the `bibliographystyle`, but I am not sure how to do it so I can get in the desired order

I don't have much experience using latex, but right now I'm using Overleaf.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: If the bibliographic entries are supposed to be listed in the order of their first citation appearance, don't use the `plain` bib style. Instead (since you mention that you use the `natbib` citation management package), employ the `unsrtnat` bib style and load the `natbib` package with the options `numbers` and `square`.

Comment: I almost got it with this info. Now i gotta make it like Lastname, name initial (year) format. Any idea on how can I do it?